# Como fazer uma requisição em um servidor utilizando certificado digital para autenticação em Python/Django

Tags: python, django

estou tentando utilizar a api de um sistema que está disponível em um link da web, porem o servidor da api requer como autenticação um certificado do tipo pem, eu já possuo este certificado, porem não consigo trazer os dados da requisição pois me retorna um erro e eu não faço idea como resolver isso.

Minha função na View

```
def IndexView(request):
   response = requests.get('https://server.com.br:4747/engine/healthcheck/', verify=True, cert=['C:/ProgramData/Qlik/Sense/Repository/Exported Certificates/client.pem', 
   'C:/ProgramData/Qlik/Sense/Repository/Exported Certificates/client_key.pem',
   'C:/ProgramData/Qlik/Sense/Repository/Exported Certificates/root.pem'])

   teste = response.json()
   return render(request, 'index.html', {
    'teste': teste,
    })
```

Erro

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='server.com.br', port=4747): Max retries exceeded with url: /engine/healthcheck/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Answer (score 1):

@Gabriel Santos, estou vendo que você misturou alguns conceitos diferentes no seu código:
1) Ao adicionar `verify = True`, você está dizendo para a lib `requests` usar o certificado SSL para a request, mas nesse caso ele vai usar o certificado padrão instalado na sua máquina. 
2) Ao adicionar o parâmetro `cert`, ele deve receber os Certificados do lado do cliente, que aceita 1 arquivo contendo a chave privada e o certificado, ou uma `tuple` com os arquivos separados.

Para resolver sua questão, basta adicionar o caminho para o seu certificado SSL no `verify`, mas somente 1 arquivo, não os 3, como você adicionou, já que só é possível usar um certificado por request.

Então, caso o primeiro arquivo que você adicionou em `cert` seja o seu SSL, basta escrever:

```
requests.get('https://server.com.br:4747/engine/healthcheck/', 
              verify='C:/ProgramData/Qlik/Sense/Repository/Exported Certificates/client.pem')
```

Veja se funciona, e caso contrário, preciso entender porque você adicionou 3 arquivos `.pem` distintos, e se possível, mostrar a documentação que está usando, para entender se existe algum conceito relacionado aos *client side certificates* que ficou perdido no caminho.

Comment: Boa tarde Luan, muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela disposição, fiz as alterações que você me pediu, ainda tenho o mesmo erro, segue abaixo a documentação da API, é bem curta e tem um exemplo em JS, acho que ficara mais fácil de você entender. 
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2018/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/GettingStarted/connecting-to-engine-api.htm

Comment: @GabrielSantos, o problema aqui não é o seu código. Pelo link que me enviou, se trata de uma conexão via websocket, e portanto não vai ser possível usando requests puramente. Através do WebSocket, o seu computador precisa rodar como um servidor para receber eventos continuamente. A ideia é abrir a conexão e então, com ela aberta, enviar e receber informações. 
Você pode dar uma olhada em libs como essa do Google (https://github.com/google/pywebsocket) ou algumas mais atuais, com suporte completo a python 3 (https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/)